# Select one value from dropdown to display values in another dropdown value in php

Tags: php, html

I have two dropdown one is category & other is product. I want to select value from category based on that i want to display value into product dropdown.

below is my code

```
<!-- <?php
//   include('session.php');
?> -->
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('product_management');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
$result = mysql_query($sql);



$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM category.c INNER JOIN products.p where WHERE       category_id.p = '$id' ";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Product Page</title>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-left: 30%;margin-top: 10%;">
        <form role="form">

            <div class="form-group">

                <label>
                    Category
                </label>
                <select name='category_type' id="category_type">
                <?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['category_id'] ."'>" . $row['category_type'] ."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">                     
                <label>
                    Products
                </label>
                 <select id="products" name="products" required>
                    <option value=""> -- SELECT -- </option>
                    <?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['products'] ."'>" . $row['products'] ."</option>";
}
?>
                </select> 
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">                     
                <label>
                    Price
                </label>
                <input type="text" id="price" name="price" required> 
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">                     
                <label>
                    Quantity
                </label>
                 <select id="quantity" name="quantity" required>
                    <option value=""> -- SELECT -- </option>
                </select> 
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="exampleInputFile">
                    Upload Image
                </label>
                <input id="exampleInputFile" type="file" />                 
            </div>



            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to achieve this? I want to Select one value from dropdown to display values in another dropdown value.

Comment: you can achieve by calling ajax.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961758/change-dropdown-value-when-another-dropdown-selected-in-a-form-using-jquery-aj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make few changes in your code, such as:

- Change the *category_type* dropdown list in the following way,

  ```
  <select name='category_type' id="category_type">
      <option value=""> -- SELECT -- </option>
  <?php
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo "<option value='" . $row['category_id'] ."'>" . $row['category_type'] ."</option>";
      }
  ?>
  </select>
  ```

  and create an empty dropdown list for *products* like this:

  ```
  <select id="products" name="products" required>
      <option value=""> -- SELECT -- </option>
  </select>
  ```
- Now use AJAX to populate the *products* dropdown list based on the selected *category_type*. Create a separate *get_products.php* page to process the AJAX request. You can use the following jQuery/AJAX code snippet to send the selected `category_id` to that page.

  ```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $(document).on('change', '#category_type', function(){
              var category_id = $(this).val();
              if(category_id.length != 0){
                  $.ajax({
                      type: 'POST',
                      url: 'get_products.php',
                      cache: 'false',
                      data: {category_id:category_id},
                      success: function(data){
                          $('#products').html(data);
                      },

                      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                          // error
                      }
                  });
              }else{
                  $('#products').html('<option value=""> -- SELECT -- </option>');
              }
          });
      });
  </script>
  ```

  And on *get_products.php* page, process your AJAX request in the following way,

  ```
  <?php

      if(isset($_POST['category_id'])){
          // your database connection code

          $id = $_POST['category_id'];
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = '$id' ";
          $result = mysql_query($sql);
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
              echo "<option value='" . $row['product_id'] ."'>" . $row['product_type'] ."</option>";
          }
      }

  ?>
  ```

  Change `$row['product_id']` and `$row['product_type']` as per your table's attribute names.

---

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_` database extensions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) driver instead. And this is [why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: if(isset($_POST['category_id'])){
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","product_management");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

Comment: I'm using this in my ajax page stil no error or result is coming

Comment: @Kirataka Did you change `url: 'get_products.php',` setting according to your page? Also, display error message in your AJAX as well, like this: `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ alert(errorThrown); }`

Comment: ya i used. but nothing happening

Comment: @Kirataka Did the *alert* message show anything? Also, paste your complete code on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/index.php) and give me it's link here.

Comment: @Kirataka It seems you didn't include jQuery library in your project. Include this line before the jQuery script, `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> `. Also, I see the URL being used is *ajax.php* in your AJAX, make sure it's correct.

Comment: included. bow dropdown is coming blank

Comment: hey bro. its coming.. sorry i missed a flower bracket. +1

Comment: @Kirataka I believe your *ajax.php* code is incorrect. You're sending `category_id` to your *ajax.php* page, not `category_type`. So your code should be like this, [http://pastebin.com/MqbqnnPR](http://pastebin.com/MqbqnnPR)